# How many three digit sequences using the numbers 0 ... 9 with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

> How many three digit sequences using the numbers 0 ... 9 with conditions
>   (a) Repetition of digits is allowed and the sequence cannot start with 0?
>   (b) Repetition of digits is not allowed and the sequence cannot start with 0?

For part (a) I did the following:
(9)(10)(10) = 900

I am stuck on part (b), I know that when you sample without replacement you want to use n!/(n-r)! But in this problem n isn't constant. The first time a digit is picked there are 9 possible digits because the sequence cannot start with 0. The second time a digit is picked there are still 9 possible digits because we are sampling without replacement and the third time a digit is picked there are 8 possible digits left. I am not sure how to combine this information to solve for part (b). Any suggestions?

Comment: Take the product like you did in part a.

Answer (score 1):

for part a, it is $9 \times 10 \times 10$ as you did.

for part b, it is $9 \times 9 \times 8$

Comment: so for part B I do not need to use the formal n!/(n-r)! ? To solve another part of the question which asked ... if repetition is not allowed? I did 10!/7! = 720. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

For part (b), using $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ will get you $\dfrac{10!}{(10-3)!}=\dfrac{10!}{7!} = 10\cdot 9\cdot 8$ options, ignoring the leading zero restriction. Then $\frac{1}{10}$ of these options will have a leading zero, so we can multiply by $\frac {9}{10}$ to get back to the valid solutions, $ \frac {9}{10}\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8 = 9\cdot 9\cdot 8 = 649$ options.

Of course you can get to the same answer by just picking available digits in succession also, as you did, just needing to multiply together the digit-by-digit results for the final answer. You can perhaps see how the two processes are just the same in different formats.